# devise sign_in page is not rendering in a seperate layout in rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, layout, devise, action

i want sepearate layout for the devise sign in action.

i am using following code,in my application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  layout :layout_by_resource

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) ||
    if resource.is_a?(User) 
      new_applicant_response_url

    else
      homepage_admin_page_path

    end
end

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "layout_name_for_devise"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end

  protected
        def configure_permitted_parameters
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:assessment_id, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
        end

end
```

and i generated the devise views and added some stylng to the devise sign in page.

when i click on devise/sign_in the following output i got in the terminal

```
Started GET "/admins/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-24 12:39:49 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/layout_name_for_devise (6.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 8.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

iam getting the layout properly for this devise sign in action. but in that layout devise sign_in form  is not rendering,only layout is rendering.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with layout. Maybe no `yield` is called in it?

Comment: yes, i forgot to add the yield statement. thanks for responding.

Comment: I added it as an answer below. Could you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout probably does not call `yield` in it.